# Using Visual Studio 2013 to analyze a database from sql server analysis services

Tags: visual-studio, ssas

I have a SQL Server database file in **ABF** format. I restored the file in sql server using the analysis services connectivity type.Now, I have to use the dimensions, cubes and other stuffs in that file in Visual Studio 2013 and do some analysis. I used the **Import from Server (Multidimensional and Data Mining )** option to load the database into the visual studio. Now the project contains cubes,data sources, dimensions, mining structures and roles. I am not sure how exactly I am suppose to use these contents and work on an analysis. Can someone please guide me through the analysis process with respect to this scenario?

FYI, I am using Microsoft's ContosoRetail Database as the ABF file. I tried to deploy the project, without making any change, just to get an idea of what the result will look like. I got 77 errors. I have included a sample screenshot of my project page, after loading the database into the visual studio, below

[image: DEPLOYMENT ERROR]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you restore the `ContosoRetailDW` database as well?

You need the SQL Server Database which can be downloaded as a backup (`.BAK`) file [from here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=18279). Restore this database to your SQL Server Database Engine and after that, go to the screen you shared and click on `ContosoRetailDW` under `Data Sources` and get the connection established to the database that you just restored; test it by clicking on `Test Connection`. Now, you can proceed to deploy your SSAS Project.

You may also find [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7qQK_P56DYU) useful.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. It is deploying without any errors. I am supposed to work with the visual studio and get a couple of analysis. I don't know how to do that. Isn't there any "Analyze in Excel" option in this type of project to import the content to excel?

Comment: Yes, there is. After deploying and processing the SSAS database, (in the same screen you shared) double click on one of the cubes and go to 'Browser' tab and click on the excel icon next to 'Language' dropdown.
Alternatively, you can go to SQL Server Management Studio and right click on cube and select 'Browse'.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. But when i open in excel, i am getting the following error 
  http://i.stack.imgur.com/7PMub.png

Comment: I think a script in your 'Calculations' tab of one of your cubes somehow refers to the member `[Date].[Calendar YQMD].[Calendar Year].&[2015]` . But when it tries to find that member in the cube, it couldn't find it, possibly because the year is not present in the `ContosoRetailDW` database. You can either try deleting this script from cube or adding the year in the date dimension of your `ContosoRetailDW` database and fully reprocessing the cube.